# c++ define and initialize struct globally

Tags: c++, struct

I'm trying to define a simple structure, have a single object of that structures type, and initialize the members of the object. When I define the structure and object globally and initialize the members within a function, it compiles and runs properly. When I try to initialize the members immediately after defining the structure and object, I get a compile error. Or at least this is what I think I'm doing, the error indicates I'm missing something somewhere.

This works (some code omitted):

```
struct globalArgs_t { //globalArgs_t is the type name
  string input_filename;
  int verbosity;
  bool choose_channel;
} arguments; // arguments is an object of type globalArgs_t

void func(){
  // Default values
  arguments.input_filename = "pic.jpg";
  arguments.verbosity = 0;
  arguments.choose_channel = false;

  //Do more stuff here
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  func();
  return 1;
}
```

But this doesn't compile (some code omitted):

```
struct globalArgs_t { //globalArgs_t is the type name
  string input_filename;
  int verbosity;
  bool choose_channel;
} arguments; // arguments is an object of type globalArgs_t;

// Default values
arguments.input_filename = "pic.jpg"; // Line 19
arguments.verbosity = 0;              // Line 20
arguments.choose_channel = false;     // Line 21

void func(){

  //Do more stuff here
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  func();
  return 1;
}
```

The error is:

```
main.cpp:19:3: error: ‘arguments’ does not name a type
main.cpp:20:3: error: ‘arguments’ does not name a type
main.cpp:21:3: error: ‘arguments’ does not name a type
```

I'm using g++ and -std=c++0x to compile, if that makes a difference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statements go inside functions. You can't put them in the "global area" like you've done there.

This is the correct syntax:

```
struct globalArgs_t { //globalArgs_t is the type name
  string input_filename;
  int verbosity;
  bool choose_channel;
} arguments = {
  "pic.jpg",
  0,
  false
};
```

This is an example of *aggregate initialization* (this struct is an aggregate).

Unfortunately, C++ doesn't support C-style tagged initialization, and you have to give the values for the members in the same order in which the members were given in the definition of the struct.

Comment: Awesome answer. Thanks. The key part that I was missing was that you can do some things outside of main but not others. So I guess you can initialize upon declaration outside of main but you can't update the values. `int a=0;` is good. But `int a; a=0;` isn't. So the syntax for initializing a structure during declaration is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

[edit: I deleted my whole post]

Once you've declared an instance of the struct, you can initialize it using a [constructor](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_constructor_destructor.htm) or [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

Comment: Well written answer but OP's issue is the *context* in which he is trying to assign the values. `arguments` actually does refer to a specific instance in the way it is declared. It's not the C `typedef struct` here.

Comment: Ah! Thanks! I missed that. Also apparently he is using this method intentionally! My fault completely!